# Self-Study: Integrating Complex function

Tags: integration

Is there a substitution approach to provide a closed-form solution to the following integral?

\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\frac{(1-p)^{k-1}(1-p+p\ln p)}{\left(\ln p\right)^2}dp
\end{equation}

Comment: In the denominator, do you mean $\ln {(p^2)}$ or do you mean ${(\ln p)}^2$?

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar - it should be clear now

Comment: Also, have you got all your terms correct? Cause if you add $pk\ln p -\ln p$ in the right bracket in the numerator, you will be looking at $-\frac{d}{dp} \left( \frac{p{(1-p)}^k}{\ln p}\right)$

Comment: Yes, the terms are correct. Perhaps this is more about adding and subtracting terms than a substitution.

Comment: In that case, even [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_0%5E1+%28%281+-+p%29%5E%28k+-+1%29+%281+-+p+%2B+p+log%28p%29%29%29%2F%28log%5E2%28p%29%29+dp&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D) is stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a reduction to a Frullani-type integral. The substitution $p=e^{-x}$ transforms it into $$I_k=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})^k\frac{dx}{x^2}-\int_0^\infty e^{-2x}(1-e^{-x})^{k-1}\frac{dx}{x}$$ which, after integration by parts in the first term, gives $$I_k=\int_0^\infty(ke^{-2x}-e^{-x})(1-e^{-x})^{k-1}\frac{dx}{x}=(k-1)J_{k-1}-kJ_k,$$ where $$J_k=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})^k\frac{dx}{x}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}(-1)^{j+1}\ln(j+1)$$ is *that very integral*; see the middle of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3400264) of mine. (I don't see further reduction.)

Comment: I was not aware of this type of integral! I am glad this question pays off with more to learn! Thank you

Comment: +1 nice solution! I too was unaware of Frullani-type integrals.